# Glossary of footnotes

Tags: footnotes, glossaries

I'm writing a book where I put in footnotes the biographies of the scientists cited. Now I want to list these entries of footnotes in a glossary "Dictionnary of the authors cited in the book". Who has an idea about this task ?

I give a simple example of my aim

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
The Maxwell\footnote{James Clerk
Maxwell, english physicist, 1831-1869}-Boltzmann\footnote{Ludwig Boltzmann,
english physicist and science philosoph, 1844-1906} model.
\end{document}
```

which gives simply this after compilation

[image]

and I want something sorted like in the page 2 in this  post..
[image]

Comment: It would help to see a short a example of those footnote - like bibliographies. The easiest way would be to use `glossaries` and some kind of `\gls{authorone}` etc., but without example... you know ;-)

Comment: Would you see my updated message

Comment: On a side note: *physician is not the correct word!!!* It's *physicist*.

Comment: @Danu ok I have been alerted about it by egreg... I'll do corrections soon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a `glossaries` solution, where the entries are stored in the glossary itself, the link display (i.e. in the body) can be changed with `\defglsentryformat`. At the moment, however, the page number is used, not the footnote number.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\newglossaryentry{Maxwell}{%
name={James Clerk Maxwell},
description={english physicist,1831-1869}
}

\newglossaryentry{Boltzmann}{%
  name={Ludwig Boltzmann},
  description={Austrian physicist,1844-1906}
}

\newglossaryentry{Einstein}{%
  name={Albert Einstein},
  description={German physicist,1879-1955}
}


\makeglossaries

\defglsentryfmt{\glsentryname{\glslabel}, \glsentrydesc{\glslabel}}

\begin{document}

The Maxwell\footnote{\gls{Maxwell}}-Boltzmann\footnote{\gls{Boltzmann}}
 model.

\clearpage
Einstein\footnote{\gls{Einstein}}-Bose-Condensate

\printglossary[title={Dictionary of Authors}]

\end{document}
```

**Update** With footnote numbers and additional glossary keys

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nomain]{glossaries}


\newglossary[aul]{authordict}{aus}{aug}{Dictionary of Authors}[Hfootnote]  %Note: Hfootnote, not just footnote

\makeglossaries


\glsaddkey{birthyear}{\glsentrytext{\glslabel}}{\glsentrybirthyear}{\GLsentrybirthyear}{\glsbirthyear}{\Glsbirthyear}{\GLSbirthyear}
\glsaddkey{deathyear}{}{\glsentrydeathyear}{\GLsentrydeathyear}{\glsdeathyear}{\Glsdeathyear}{\GLSdeathyear}




\newglossaryentry{Maxwell}{%
name={James Clerk Maxwell},
birthyear={1831},
deathyear={1869},
description={English physicist},
type=authordict,
}

\newglossaryentry{Boltzmann}{%
  name={Ludwig Boltzmann},
  birthyear={1844},
  deathyear={1906},
  description={Austrian physicist},
  type=authordict
}

\newglossaryentry{Einstein}{%
  name={Albert Einstein},
  birthyear={1879},
  deathyear={1955},
  description={German physicist},
  type=authordict
}



\defglsentryfmt[authordict]{\glsentryname{\glslabel} (\glsentrybirthyear{\glslabel} -- \glsentrydeathyear{\glslabel}), \glsentrydesc{\glslabel}}



\begin{document}

The Maxwell\footnote{\gls{Maxwell}}-
Boltzmann\footnote{\gls{Boltzmann}}
 model.


\clearpage
Einstein\footnote{\gls{Einstein}}
-Bose-Condensate


\printglossary[type=authordict]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok The solution (so simple !) based on glossaries is exactly my purpose Thanks

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna: Well, thanks for accepting, but I've added a better version with footnote numbers and it does not interfere with other glossaries

Comment: Thanks for the add. I have another problem. I want to put in the footnotes "small information" e.g. name and dates of birth-death, and in the glossary more information e.g. their life, the development on some theories using their work etc... I haven't found in the doc how I can do "two descriptions" one small and one with more details ...

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna: You can add extra keys (such as 'name', 'desc') with `\glsaddkey` -- please have a look into the manual `glossaries-user.pdf` (not the shorter `glossaries-begin.pdf`

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna: Updated with `\glsaddkey` example and better usage of the `footnote` counter

Comment: I have 2-3 problems in your solution:

             1/ I have too many footnotes in my file so I use the fnsymbol counter for numbering it. So I want glossaries to be numbered by pages

2/ from where do come from your notation Hfootnote ? I have exactly the same notation for use with the manyfoot package. I tried with another notation but it's not accepted. can you change this notation?

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna: Now you're changing the question actually. Your initial post did not reveal anything about `fnsymbol` or `manyfoot`

Comment: I don't think that there's problems of using fnsymbol of the footnote counter if we use your first solution which gives the number of the page not of the footnote... Is there aompatibility problems between the manyfoot and glossaries packages?

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna: If you just want to have page references for the glossary entries, then remove the `[Hfootnote]` -- page numbering is the default for `glossaries`. And `Hfootnote` is the counter needed by `hyperref`. I've never used manyfoot so far.

Comment: I have another question please. I've produced the glossary using the command prompt and saw that the output produced is the {name}, after the {description}, after the page number. My question is: "How can I custom the output produced by \printglossary ? e.g. add more informations, like birth and death dates, nationality... etc, in the output

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna: You are aware that you are changing the question (again)?

Comment: Sorry I'll open another discussion later after reading the doc of the package, which is so hard... I'll refer to this discussion also. Many thanks

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna: Yes, do so please. The manual is a little bit strange but after some time it's easier ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with an index. I don't think that repeating the information is worthwhile. If you also load `hyperref` (after `imakeidx`), the page numbers will become hyperlinks pointing to the page containing the relevant footnote.

```
\documentclass[
  openany, % just for this example
]{book}

\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry} % just for this example

\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex[title=Dictionary of the authors cited in the book]

\begin{document}

\chapter{Models}

The Maxwell%
  \footnote{James Clerk Maxwell, english physicist, 1831--1869}%
  \index{Maxwell, James Clerk}%
--Boltzmann%
  \footnote{Ludwig Boltzmann, austrian physicist and philosopher of science, 1844--1906}%
  \index{Boltzmann, Ludwig}
model.

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that a “physician” is a medical doctor; “physics is what physicists do late in the night” wrote Jay Orear in his book on physics.

Comment: haha..physics .. you understand.. I'm writing my book in arabic and have quickly translated my biographies.. 
Thanks for the idea but there can be some problem with this...
1/ I'm using an index of scientific words than I must use a package enabling multi-indexing
2/ In arabic we sort the names by first names not by the second ones so I must have an entry for the first and one entry for the second and sort by the first one

Comment: 3/ I can't add some description like the biography in the index... So if I decide to put the biographies at the end of the book and refer to it in the footnotes, I can't do this with an index...

Comment: I think that the good solution is to make a glossary where the description of each entry is the footnote of the entry

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna `imakeidx` supports multiple indices.

Comment: thanks I have information about it. It's in the doc and I'll read it for some ideas..